# Constantly getting NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am making a program in which it encrypts words into some kind of secret message, but I keep on getting an error. Yes, I know the code is ugly... but I am a beginner. 
Here is my main.

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String args []){

    String message;
    message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give me something to crypt!");
    Crypt secret = new Crypt();
    secret.CyptedMessage(message);
}

}
```

Here is my class.

```
public class Crypt {

String letter[];
String message;

public Crypt(){
    message = "";
    letter[0]="A";
    letter[1]="B";
    letter[2]="C";
    letter[3]="D";
    letter[4]="E";
    letter[5]="F";
    letter[6]="G";
    letter[7]="H";
    letter[8]="I";
    letter[9]="J";
    letter[10]="K";
    letter[11]="L";
    letter[12]="M";
    letter[13]="N";
    letter[14]="O";
    letter[15]="P";
    letter[16]="Q";
    letter[17]="R";
    letter[18]="S";
    letter[19]="T";
    letter[20]="U";
    letter[21]="V";
    letter[22]="W";
    letter[23]="X";
    letter[24]="Y";
    letter[25]="Z";
    letter[26]=" ";
}

int getRandomCrypt(){
    //Random number 1 to 25
    int x;
    x=(int)(1 + Math.random()*25);
    return x;
}

int checkLetter(String subMessage){
    //Checks letters
    boolean b = false;
    int i=0;
    while (b = false){

        if (i == 27){
            i=0;

        if (subMessage == letter[i])
            return i;


        else
            i++;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void CyptedMessage(String message){

    String CyptedMessage = null;
    String message1;
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
        int number = checkLetter(message.substring(i, i+1));
        message1 = letter[number + getRandomCrypt()];
        if (number + getRandomCrypt()>26){
            message1 = letter[i-27];
        }
        CyptedMessage += message1;
    } 

    System.out.print(CyptedMessage);
}


}
```

When I run this I get...

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Crypt.<init>(Crypt.java:9)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: String letter[] = new String[27];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Serge pointed out, String letter[] is an array declaration, not an initialization.  You need to then initialize it to define an exact size.

```
public Crypt(){
    letter = new String[27]; //define array
    message = "";
    letter[0]="A";
    letter[1]="B";
    letter[2]="C";
    letter[3]="D";
    letter[4]="E";
    letter[5]="F";
    letter[6]="G";
    letter[7]="H";
    letter[8]="I";
    letter[9]="J";
    letter[10]="K";
    letter[11]="L";
    letter[12]="M";
    letter[13]="N";
    letter[14]="O";
    letter[15]="P";
    letter[16]="Q";
    letter[17]="R";
    letter[18]="S";
    letter[19]="T";
    letter[20]="U";
    letter[21]="V";
    letter[22]="W";
    letter[23]="X";
    letter[24]="Y";
    letter[25]="Z";
    letter[26]=" ";
}
```

Edit: forgot ;
And others beat me :P

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your `String letter[];` and directly adding values into it
do this in your constructor 
`letter = new String[size];`

or do this in starting `String letter[] = new String[size];`

and in your case `size` is `27`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize you array ans not just define it.

```
String letter[] = new String[27];
```

Also you can put a NPE check before using the array data

```
if(letter[number + getRandomCrypt()] != null)
   message1 = letter[number + getRandomCrypt()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `String letter[];` is not instantiated.

add  `letter = new String[size];` in your Constructor of Crypt before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

**In class Crypt, you declare a string array named letters, but you do not initialize it when you use it. That is why you encounter a NullPointerException.**

Initilize it before you use it.

public Crypt(){

```
**letter= new String[27];**
letter[0]="A";
letter[1]="B";
... ...
```

}